# Hide the footer of web page on android's web view

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-webview

This seems like an easy task but I cant manage to do it. 
I am loading http://beta.tfl.gov.uk/plan-a-journey/ on a web view and I want to remove the footer from display:
[image]

On my web view I have tried several things but I see no result in page loading

```
 @Override public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
         {
            wburl.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                     "document.getElementsByTagName('primary-footer')[0].style.display=\"none\"; " +
                     "})()");
         }
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Probably you can use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

instead of loadUrl()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try fetching the page programatically (you can use HttpUrlConnection) and then modify the page (add .footer{display:none;} in the header styles) and load the modified page on the webview.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 640px){
 .footer{display:none;}
}
```

Here i put the 640px resolution if your android mobile resolution varied means put it that resolution.
This is CSS style.this one is enough no need oj jquery

Comment: It is not possible (or I am not aware of) to apply the CSS file to the web page url loaded from the server...